# CircuiTikZ logic gates

Tags: circuitikz

How can i draw a circuit like this using circuitikz?

[image: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/1/6/43-xor_circuit.png]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? For logic gates see CircuiTikZ manual, section *3.24 Logic gates*, page 97. At bottom of the page 101 you can find some examples of elementary logic circuits. This can serve for starting point. Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174663/colorful-logic-gates-using-circuitikz?rq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332639/logic-gates-circuitikz?rq=1. Both questions are quite similar what you like to draw.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  I looked at them both but couldn't make it at all.

Comment: Have you spent your four or five hours to give it a real try?  Unless you're asking for someone to draw your circuit for you, that's about the minimum amount of time you need to learn to do anything useful in circuitikz from a zero start

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will make it like that after this time. Sorry for taking time

Comment: And also how can i learn circuitikz very well? Any other sources than documentation?

Comment: @electroman you can read a bit in the `pgfmanual`, `circuitikz` uses Ti*k*Z below the hood and most of the syntax is "just" Ti*k*Z. Also the `circuitikz` manual has quite a few examples and a tutorial inside.

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following draws your logic circuit. Everything is placed relative to A and if you change something in the A path, the B path should stretch/shrink accordingly.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate[label={[left]$A$}](A)
    to[short,-*] ++(.35,0) coordinate(jA)
    -- ++(.25,0) node[american not port, anchor=west](notA){} (notA.east)
    node[american and port, anchor=in 1](andA){}
    (A) ++(0, -2) coordinate[label={[left]$B$}](B)
    to[short,-*] ($(B-|jA)+(0.1,0)$) coordinate(jB)
    -- (B-|notA.west) node[american not port, anchor=west](notB){} (notB.east)
    node[american and port, anchor=in 2](andB){}
    (jA) -- ($(jA)!.8!(jA|-andB.in 1)$) -| (andB.in 1) -- +(.01,0)
    (jB) -- ($(jB)!.8!(jB|-andA.in 2)$) -| (andA.in 2) -- +(.01,0)
    ($(A)!.5!(B)$) coordinate(vc)
    (vc-|andB.out) node[american or port, anchor=west](or){}
    (andA.out) ++(-.01,0) -| (or.in 1) -- +(0.01,0)
    (andB.out) ++(-.01,0) -| (or.in 2) -- +(0.01,0)
    (or.out) node[right]{$(\bar{A}\cdot B)+(A\cdot\bar{B})=A\oplus B$}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your precious answer.